# How to get a combined ticket in IRCTC (Indian Railway)

Tags: trains, tickets, india, bookings, train-stations

Suppose I want to go from Station A to Station C but Station C is not a stoppage of some train say train 01, so I can get a combined ticket from station A to Station B  through train 01 plus Station B to station C through a different train say 02, so my total fare will be of same ticket as from Station A to Station C.

We can get Combined ticket from the Booking Window but how's that possible on the IRCTC website?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say with "stoppage". In British/American/Australian English a stoppage would be something like a strike by union workers. Indian English is often different though. Maybe you mean a station that a train stops at?

Comment: I did edit the question, but this part I wasn't sure how to edit so I asked for clarification. So you mean an unscheduled stop?

Comment: yes you are correct @hippietrail

Comment: Yes, it is possible by merging the two ticket let say A to B (travel with train 1) & B to C (travel with another train) in a single ticket A to C (switching the train at station B). But this only happens with the Window ticket not for the online ticket. I have merge 3 tickets in a single ticket. Advantage of merging is reducing some amount from the total amount. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if the station C is enroute station A and B, you can't take a ticket from A to C and use it in the way described even from a booking window.

However, if the station B lies between stations A and C, and you want to travel from A to C, you can buy a ticket from A to C and then do two reservations of it. The first reservation would be combined with the first ticket and second would need to be done separately.

This facility is not available on IRCTC since the e-tickets are only valid for travel with confirmed reservation. So, if you have a reservation from A to B, your ticket will also be from A to B only.

You will have to it from a booking window / agent if you want to avail the telescopic rates.

Comment: You are wrong, Please read my above comment.